# parse cURL response in PHP using preg_match() not working

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I have cURL response in PHP like this, and I want only get the `<a:RefNo>A1231640000001</a:RefNo>` content only. I have tried simpleXML() but I failed, I use also preg_match() but I'm having a hard time..

Comment: you ran it through htmlspecialchars(), so you don't have `<a` anymore, you have `&lt;a` And that's a soap response. you shouldn't be parsing it with regex or string operations.

Comment: Use a [SOAP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).

Comment: @MarcB what should I need to do to parse it?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I use already that, but it wont work on mine. That's why I used cURL.

Comment: Then perhaps that should be your actual question. "How do I get this SOAP request to work correctly in PHP?"

Comment: it works on my mine, doesn't need that. @Phylogenesis what I need to do is to parse the content inside soap response.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your XML have a error in this line, because your open tag `a:Signature` is without `>`

```
<a:SignatureJJqwH0QlPO9QQ/f9FT4G8q+I/zdIILLtxETLgrAZuolVCgqIdhNxuw3xgusq1HqxcGG6TZZIkwlylgI3VbWLJQ==</a:Signature>
```

Verify if is it just a typo or if your WebService is sending the response with this error.

Next, avoid to use regex to parse XML in this level (Let the core do it for you ;-)). Here a example of using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse your XML (corrected):

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);

    ///getting the Signatute tag and Partner RefNo
    $signature = $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://domain.com','Signature');
    $partner = $dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://domain.com','PartnerRefNo');
    print_r ($signature->item(0)->nodeValue);
    print_r ("\n\n");
    print_r ($partner->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

The result is:

> JJqwH0QlPO9QQ/f9FT4G8q+I/zdIILLtxETLgrAZuolVCgqIdhNxuw3xgusq1HqxcGG6TZZIkwlylgI3VbWLJQ==
>
> A1231640000001

**OBS**: To deal with SOAP WebSErvices, prefer to use the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php). Use cURL only as a last option.

Comment: @James  I think you can put the xml  with encapsulation. (Replace sensitive Information like Id, Password with ***.)